# Multi table pagination

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, pagination

If you have the following function:
How to add LIMIT sequence for each table ?

```
function find($page=2,$num_of_page=30){
   $query_1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_1";
   $query_2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_2";
   $query_3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_3";

   .
   .
   .
   /*
   $total_count   == 100;
   $table_1_count ==  33;
   $table_2_count ==  10;
   $table_3_count ==  57; 
   */

   $offset = $page -1 * $num_of_page;
   $limit  = $num_of_page;
   .
   .

}
```

if  $page == 2 and $num_of_page ==30;
you should execute

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 LIMIT 30,3
SELECT * FROM table_2 LIMIT 0,10
SELECT * FROM table_3 LIMIT 0,17
```

Please forgive my ugly English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these tables all have the same structure, you could do `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table3` and then using a single `LIMIT` for the query.

Comment: Here my  table having millions of rows and union will take much more time to fetch the data

is there any way that it will first fetch first table if desired records set found then skip the rest 

if found some records but not the total expeted then it should look for second table to pad up the records and the same continues

Comment: I haven't looked at the query plan in this sort of scenario. If what you describe isn't already what's happening, you should first try `UNION ALL` as that will avoid checking for duplicates. If that still doesn't work, you'll probably have to query each table separately.